# How to mark stage as unstable if Powershell condition results into true?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a .Net 5 solution and build the projects with code style analysis. Each violated rule results in a warning. But the build command exits with the code 0.

I created a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file that should mark the pipeline as unstable if any build warnings have been thrown.

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

stages:
  - build
  - unit-tests

build:
  stage: build
  script:
      - |-
        dotnet build --output build -consoleloggerparameters:"Summary;Verbosity=normal" -m -p:"WarnLevel=5;EnforceCodeStyleInBuild=true" -t:"clean,build" -fl1 "/flp1:warningsonly";

        if ((!$LASTEXITCODE) -and (Get-Content "msbuild1.log"))
        {
          # >>> mark stage as unstable here <<<
        }
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build

unit-tests:
  stage: unit-tests
  script:
    - dotnet test --no-build --output build
  dependencies:
    - build
```

The stage itself passes but I was hoping that it passes with an unstable state (because of the warnings), unfortunately it's green.

A **bad** solution would be adding the `-warnaserror` flag for the build command and use `allow_failure: true` for the stage. This would set the stage into an unstable state but next stages would fail because of the missing build.

So what would be the correct way to check if the build command finished with warnings to mark the stage as unstable?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this would be what you are looking for but my understanding is that your `unit-tests` depends on the previous `code-quality` or `build` step (or both)?
In this case you modify your `unit-tests` step to be something like:

```yaml
unit-tests:
  stage: unit-tests
  script:
    - dotnet test --no-build --output build
  # replace 'dependencies' with 'needs'
  needs:
    - job: build
      artifacts: true
    - job: code-quality
```

The consequences would be that if the build fails your pipeline will fail, in case the `code-quality` step fails it will still be able to run the `unit-tests`, except when the test step would depend on artifacts from code quality step